# Passing a char * to a function and getting a return value....Is this the Correct way?

Tags: c

```
char * func(char * str)
{
    char *ptr = (char *)malloc(strlen(str));
    sprintf(ptr,"%s",str);
    * (ptr +1) = 'E'; 
    printf("%s\n",ptr);
    return ptr;
}

void main()
{
    char * str = "kundan";
    char * str1 = func(str);
    printf("%s\n",str1);
    free(str1);
    printf("%s\n",str1);
}
```

This is a very basic question but I am confused. I am sending a char * to a function and receiving a return value which is also char *. I cannot use stack memory in func() for the return as it will expire as soon func call is over. So , I am allocating memory in heap and returning it. Please suggest if there is better means and the memory which I am freeing in main is the right way of working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use a pointer after you have given it to `free()`, because the memory that the pointer pointed to is no longer available for you to read or write. Using a pointer after you have freed it results in undefined behaviour. In your case, it may print the string again, or it may crash.

Also, don't forget, that strings in C require an extra `char` to hold the `'\0'` character (terminating null character).

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| k | u | n | d | a | n | \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The length of the string is 6, but it occupies 7 `char` in memory, so when you call `malloc` and only give it the length of the string, you won't have enough space for the the null character. Again, the operating system might give you extra anyway and it may be working in this case for you, but never rely on this, you must only use the number of bytes that you asked for.

Comment: @dreamlax...thanks...I tried to print the ptr after freeing it just to check the output. I just wanted to confirm whether this way of working is correct. Thanks You

Answer (score 5):

There are probably multiple ways to do that.  For example, it would be possible to pass a second parameter that points to a buffer (e.g., possibly one on the stack in the calling function) that the information is written to.  If you chose that route, you would probably also want to pass the length of the buffer so that the function could make sure it did not overwrite past the end of the memory.

The current method is probably reasonable (depending on the goals).  However, the call to `malloc` needs to be one byte longer for the null terminator:

```
char *ptr = (char *)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

Also, `strcpy` could be used after that to copy the input to that allocated buffer.  That would typically be the more common method:

```
strcpy( ptr, str );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test return value of malloc, because it can be NULL if malloc fail memory allocating. If you dont need modify input string, you should declare function parameter as const char * ptr.

Comment: Testing the result of `malloc` has become less and less useful. Some operating systems implement something called "overcommitting". Basically, when you call `malloc` it will always give you a valid pointer (even if you ask for some insane amount of memory) and it won't actually cause problems until you try and use all of it. Therefore, the result of `malloc` is rarely `NULL` on these systems. Also, there is not a lot that can be done anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially not allocate or return anything; instead, let the user perform the allocation:

```
void func(char *dst, char * str)
{
    assert(strlen(dst)>=strlen(src))
    sprintf(dst,"%s",str);
    * (dst +1) = 'E'; 
    printf("%s\n",dst);
}
```

You would then call `func` like so:

```
void main()
{
    char str[] = "kundan";
    char str1[sizeof str] = {0,};
    func(str1, str);
    printf("%s\n",str1);
    printf("%s\n",str1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between returning an allocated buffer and writing to a caller provided buffer (see Dave's answer) is who is responsible for freeing that memory.

When you want to return a freshly created 'object' (like a char buffer - by object I mean a pointer to some data) you need to malloc it in the function. Then the caller of the function is responsible for freeing that buffer when he no longer needs it.
This might obviously lead to memory leaks if the free is forgotten. Also depending on the type of the returned object it might be difficult or impossible for the caller to determine the size of the object.

Therefore C-functions often don't return an allocated heap 'object' but require the caller to provide a writable buffer as a parameter where the return value is written to. In that case the caller is less likely to forget to free his buffer and will always know its size because he himself allocated it.

When you want to return new allocated buffers you should give your function a name that reflects this behavior. For example you could start the function name with `new` or `create` so it is clear that new memory is allocated by this function and must be freed later.  Good names would be something like `char* createXXXFromXXX(char* parameter)` or `char* newXXXWithXXX(char* parameter)`